# imputing missing values by the mean of last week and next week

Tags: python-3.x

i have a dataframe with columns of date, time stamp and usage. The time stamp is taken for every 15 mins of the day i.e., a total of 96 readings for each day. I have few missing values in the data frame.

1. I want to impute those missing values with the mean of the last week same day same time and next week same day same time.
2. If they are also missing then the previous week and the next week and so on.
3. If the missing values are in the first line then the values must be imputed by the values of the next week same day same time.
4. If the missing values are in the last line then they must be imputed by the values of the last week same day same time

I am trying achieve this functionality using nested for loops. but couldn't do it.